# Se pued hacer esto en SQL sever?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

Esta consulta la vi en ORACLE, Quisiera saber si tambien sirve para SQL SERVER 2008R2?

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM PS_GameData.dbo.Chars FOR UPDATE
```

Osea NO es crear un update separado para eso no pregunto nada, me refiero a hacer el select sale un resultado ejmplo:

```
+----+----+
|RowX|Juan|
+----+----+
```

Editar manualmente el resulñtado SIN UPDATE table set nombre =nombre where Rowx = rowx

```
+----+----+
|RowX|raul|
+----+----+
```

Comment: ¿Qué intentas hacer con esa consulta? ¿Un `SELECT`, `UPDATE` ...?

Comment: Si no me equivoco esta instrucción bloquea los update sobre el objeto o no? de ser así, si se puede

Comment: Por favor revisar: [Recomendaciones para escribir un buen título](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title/10648#10648)

Comment: segun vi en oracle o entendi es un select que me permite buscar un registro y directo en el resultado de forma manual puedo editar el resultado NO es crear un segundo Update tabla set edit =edit where tipo =tipo eso no lo quiero hacer quiero es editar directo del resultado del select

Comment: Me parece que no entendiste el propósito de `SELECT...FOR UPDATE`. No es para editar manualmente el resultado, sino para bloquear filas que se usarán después en un `UPDATE`. Lo que quieres hacer es una pésima práctica que debe evitarse para no bloquear filas durante un tiempo excesivo. Sí existe la opción en SQL Server pero mi integridad me impide compartirla.

Answer (score 0):

Si no usas tablas cluster, también puedes usar la opción UPDLOCK, pero solo si tienes un indice en la columna por la que estas bloqueando (en este caso el indice se llama 'tableIdx'):

```
SELECT * FROM tuTabla WITH (UPDLOCK, INDEX(tableIdx)) WHERE id=1
```

Si lo que quieres es bloquear durante un UPDATE y no quieres que otra transaccion interfiera puedes usar [ROWLOCK](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-2017):

```
UPDATE tuTabla (ROWLOCK) SET columna = valor WHERE id=1
```

Si tu intención es hacer varias operaciones lo ideal sería envolverlas en una transacción.

-- Editado --

Como veo que puede haber una confusion sobre qué es el *SELECT ... FOR UPDATE* de Oracle, paso a explicarlo:
Oracle ofrece varias opciones para solucionar problemas de concurrencia, pasando por los Isolation levels a nivel de configuración de tablas o instancias de bases de datos.

El propósito de un SELECT FOR UPDATE es únicamente el bloquear el registro seleccionado para evitar que otra transacción modifique dicho registro simultáneamente, creando así una transacción propia durante el mismo query. Evidentemente, solo se pueden bloquear aquellos registros que no estan bloqueados y **al ser una consulta DML debe terminarse confirmando o rechazando la transacción con su correspondiente COMMIT o ROLLBACK** respectivamente.

En SQL Server también se pueden utilizar estos niveles de aislamiento a nivel de instancia, pero a nivel de query se pueden utilizar hints como ROWLOCK o UPDLOCK con mucho cuidado y conociendo bien el funcionamiento de dichos hints ya que pueden provocar bloqueos si no se cierran correctamente las transacciones.

Comment: no tiene nada que ver con la respuesta estas separando un select para despues crear un Update separado no es la edicion apartir del resultado

Comment: para aclararlo, el SELECT FOR UPDATE de Oracle se utiliza para bloquear un registro en concreto y prevenir así modificaciones simultáneas de otras transacciones. Por eso te doy varias opciones, no que utilices un select y luego un update, porque la pregunta ayer no estaba clara.

Answer (score -1):

Tienes 2 opciones, la flexible y la no flexible.
La no flexible permite actualizar sólo el número de filas especificadas en un TOP

```
CREATE TABLE #Ejemplo(
    id  int,
    Texto varchar(10)
);

INSERT INTO #Ejemplo
VALUES( 1, 'A'), ( 2, 'B'), ( 3, 'C'), ( 4, 'D');
GO
UPDATE TOP (1) e SET
    Texto = 'Prueba'
 FROM #Ejemplo e;

SELECT *
FROM #Ejemplo;

GO
DROP TABLE #Ejemplo;
```

En la opción flexible, usas un CTE para definir las filas que vas a actualizar. Usando la tabla del ejemplo anterior:

```
WITH cteEjemplo AS(
    SELECT TOP (1) *
    FROM #Ejemplo
    ORDER BY id DESC
)
UPDATE cteEjemplo SET
    Texto = 'Prueba';
```

Si lo que quieres es bloquear la tabla mediante un `SELECT` para luego actualizarla, no se puede. Y no se puede porque cualquier instrucción `SELECT` puede convertirse fácilmente en un `UPDATE`.